# Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x + y$ is not rational, then $x$ or $y$ must be irrational.

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I am trying to prove that the statement "Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x + y$ is not rational, then $x$ or $y$ must be irrational." is true using proof by contradiction.

The following is my proof.

---

Suppose that the negation of the statement is true.

It follows that $x+y$ is irrational and both $x$ and $y$ are rational.

Thus,

\begin{equation}
x+y = \frac{p}{q} + \frac{r}{s} \text{ where $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q,s \ne 0$}
\end{equation}

Re-expressing the $RHS$ of the above equation, one obtains

\begin{equation}
x+y = \frac{ps + rq}{qs}\text{ where $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q,s \ne 0$}
\end{equation}

Since the $LHS$ of the equation is irrational and the $RHS$ is rational, one obtains a contradiction.

Therefore, if $x+y$ is irrational then $x$ or $y$ must be irrational.

---

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Correct , a classic proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Approxiz Yes! The proof is correct.

Comment: Also compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483488/prove-that-if-the-sum-of-two-numbers-is-irrational-then-at-least-one-of-the-numb?rq=1).

Comment: I can't see any reason to why this post should attract any downvotes. The question is clear and well written, and OP presents his thoughts clearly and structured.

Comment: You are 100% correct and works. I would mention that this proof doesn't really need to use contradiction. You have actually directly shown the contrapostive, so you can remove the contradiction bits for a (slightly) more consise proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems correct to me.

---

Alternatively, we can make the proof shorter:

Suppose that, $x+y \in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q.$

Then if $x,y \in\mathbb Q$, we get $x+y\in\mathbb Q$, which gives a contradiction. Thus, we can at least conclude that $x\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ or $y\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q.$